# find key and create new object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array of objects:

```
[{
    "f_name":"nand",
    "lastName":"bhatt",
    "gender":"",
    "email":"chuchubhatt@webuters.com",
    "mobileNo":"0043 664 321 54 76",
    "company":"IBM Bhimtal"
}, {
    "f_name":"Pooran",
    "lastName":"Pradhan",
    "gender":"male",
    "email":"pp@wt.com",
    "mobileNo":"13123123123",
    "company":"Google"
}, {
    "f_name":"Krishna",
    "lastName":"Bhatt",
    "gender":"Male",
    "email":"krishna@wt.com", "mobileNo":"983232324",
    "company":"IBM"
}];
```

I want a new object similar to this:

```
[
  {
  field_name:f_name, sample: ['nand','Pooran','Krishna'],
  field_name:lastName, sample: ['bhatt','Pradhan','Bhatt'],
  field_name:gender, sample: ['','male','Male'],
  field_name:email, sample:  ['chuchubhatt@webuters.com','pp@wt.com','krishna@wt.com'],
  field_name:mobileNo, sample: ['0043 664 321 54 76','13123123123','983232324'],
 }]
```

Any idea how should we do this in lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
_(collection)
    .map(_.keys)
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .map(function(item) {
        return {
            field_name: item,
            sample: _.pluck(collection, item)
        };
    }).value();
```

The first three calls to [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten), and [uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq), gets you an array of keys to work with. The next call to `map()` generates the output collection. Since you're mapping the keys, the `field_name` property is just the `item` argument. The `sample` property uses [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) to sample all the field values from the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the end you want to have an array of objects rather than one object. If I understood correctly - use the combination of `lodash` functions (link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vuleganowu/1/)):

```
_.reduce(arr, function(result, item, index) {
  _.forEach(item, function(value, key) {
    var resulted = _.find(result, { field_name: key });
    if (!resulted) {
      resulted = { field_name: key, sample: [] };
      result.push(resulted);
    }
    resulted.sample.push(value);
  });
  return result;
}, []);
```